# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un objeto y filtrarlo por uno de sus elementos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, javascript-objeto

Tengo un problema que seguro que para vosotros es muy básico:

Estoy aprendiendo **nodejs** y al hacer un **find** a la base de datos me trae un objeto que luego mando a la vista, hago un **for** y lo pongo bonito.

El problema viene porque dentro de una propiedad del objeto tiene otro **array**, aquí viene mi pregunta... ¿puedo ordenar dentro de un **for** ese **array** y listarlo, por ejemplo, por categorías?

```
{
   "nombre": "lola",
   "edad" : "25"
   "amigos" : {
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "juana",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "Pepito",
        "relacion" : "trabajo"
       }
}

{
   "nombre": "Pedro",
   "edad" : "30"
   "amigos" : {
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "juana",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "Pepito",
        "relacion" : "trabajo"
       }
}
```

Renderizar con este objeto en la vista de una forma que quede:

```
Nombre Lola
Amigos colegio   Amigos trabajo
Juan             Pepito
Juana

Nombre Pedro
Amigos colegio   Amigos trabajo
Juan             Pepito
Juana
```

Comment: Eso no es algo para filtar, tu arreglo ya lo tienes ordenado, solo debes imprimir tu data con un ciclo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como dice Riven no hay necesidad de ordenar.

Necesitarías ordenar si quisieras cambiar el orden del array para que salieran primero los amigos del colegio y luego los del trabajado. Pero al renderizar los datos no tienes necesidad de eso.

Por ejemplo..

```js
const contactos = [{
   "nombre": "lola",
   "edad" : "25",
   "amigos" : [
       {
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "juana",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "Pepito",
        "relacion" : "trabajo"
       }
    ]
},
{
   "nombre": "Pedro",
   "edad" : "30",
   "amigos" : [{
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "juana",
        "relacion" : "colegio"
       },
       {
        "nombre" : "Pepito",
        "relacion" : "trabajo"
       }]
}];

for (let contacto of contactos) {
  const amigos = contacto['amigos'];
  
  for (let amigo of amigos) {
  
    if (!contacto[amigo.relacion])
      contacto[amigo.relacion] = [];
      
    contacto[amigo.relacion].push(amigo.nombre);
  }
}

console.log(contactos);
```